# Удалить последнее слово в строке с помощью «preg_replace()»

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как из следующей строки убрать последнее слово, то есть «темно-розовый»:

```
$str = 'Чехол Hoco Business Litchi для iPad 2/3/4 темно-розовый';
```

Или подправте мой вариант:

```
preg_replace('/^\s*((\S+[\s$]+){1,9}).*/', '\\1', $str);
```

Comment: Так логичнее, мне кажется, заменить все от последнего пробела до конца строки пустой строкой:  

    preg_replace("/\\s\\S+$/u", "", $text);

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ из комментария.**

---

Чтобы удалить последнее слово в строке, логично заменить всё от последнего пробела до конца строки:

```
=\s\S+$=
```

---

**Пример:**

```
$str = 'Чехол Hoco Business Litchi для iPad 2/3/4 темно-розовый';

$res = preg_replace('=\s\S+$=', '', $str);

var_dump($res);
```

---

**Фиддл:** https://repl.it/CgKL.